# Get reference to NSObject parent from UIView property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsobject

I have a `(NSObject) Block *my_block` with a `UIView *main_view` as property. On the ViewController I add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the `main_view`, so the gesture method must be on the ViewController. Is there already a way to know the `my_block` owner of the specific `main_view` from the gesture method?

This is because I have a `NSMutableArray` of `Block`. The `Blocks` are added to the `NSMutableArray` on runtime.

My first idea was a loop through the `NSMutableArray` comparing each `main_view` to the `UIView` of the recognizer. Another idea was to subclass the `UIView` and create a reference to its respective `Block`. But maybe there is a cleaner way to do it.

Here is a simple example of my classes and methods.

## Block.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Block : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *main_view;

@end
```

## ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Block.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // the Blocks are actually added on runtime to a NSMutableArray, but this is a simpler example

    Block *my_block = [[Block alloc] init];
    [[my_block main_view] addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)]];
    [self.view addSubview:[my_block main_view]];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    Block *block_temp = [recognizer.view ....];
    //recognizer.view = main_view, how to get the Block owner of this view?
}
```

Comment: Why Block can't be the view itself? I mean, Block : UIView? Then you add the gesture to the block instead of the main_view.

Comment: From your question "the gesture method must be on the ViewController" - why is this the case?

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira because in another part of the code I need it to be like that.

Comment: @Rich it is not my case, I assumed the Recognizer method MUST be in the ViewController, I never knew it could be in another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you `Block` classes be the `target` for your gesture recogniser:

**Block.h**

```
@interface Block : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *main_view;

@end
```

**Block.m**

```
@implementation Block

-(void)handleMainViewPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // Now recognizer.view is the same view as self.main_view
    // Use self as this is now your block
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // the Blocks are actually added on runtime to a NSMutableArray, but this is a simpler example

    Block *my_block = [[Block alloc] init];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:my_block action:@selector(handleMainViewPan:)];
    [my_block.main_view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [self.view addSubview:my_block.main_view];
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks!! This worked perfectly. How I said, I never knew that the GestureRecognizerMethods could be outside the UIViewControllers. Another point I like about this answers is that encapsulation is used.

Comment: Yeah I was going to mention that, but I have no idea about your code, because you mentioned the array you were keeping :D Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subclassing UIView you can also use functions:

```
void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)
id objc_getAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key)
```

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject)

> Sets an associated value for a given object using a given key and
>   association policy.

Good article http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/

Answer (score 0):

If you already have **blocks** in array (I believe that array is a property in `ViewController`) you can find block with one for `loop`.

Example:

```
// self.blocks is NSMutableArray where blocks are stored

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    Block *owner = nil;
    for (block in self.blocks) {
        if (block.main_view == recognizer.view) {
            owner = block;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```